# Prevent redirection to root url

Tags: php, asp.net, session, redirect

i am trying to access a webpage. I manage to get the redirect webpage session id as shown: 
`http://www.sbstransit.com.sg/mobileiris/(tqkjtlnqkh2lw5v4rz4yurzf)/mobresult_svclist.aspx?stopcode=16101`

I added `mobresult_svclist.aspx?stopcode=16101` after the session id to retrieve the information.

However, i could not access the page and keep been redirected to the root url: `http://www.sbstransit.com.sg/mobileiris/(tqkjtlnqkh2lw5v4rz4yurzf)/index_nextbus.aspx?__redir=1`.

Do anyone know how to prevent that redirection to the root url using php or any other codes? Thanks.

Comment: `i am trying to access a webpage` Are you using a webbrowser?

Comment: What is this for? Probably the server does not want you to "access" the page that way. Why dont you just use a browser?

Comment: yea i am using a web browser to access.. however each time i access the url. the url show "Object has been moved to here". and i am redirected back to the root url.

Comment: Then it probably doesn't exist anymore or the webmaster doesn't want you to navigate to that particular URL.

Comment: @user - I am trying to get data using php so if i can would prevent using web browser. i know the server does not want me to access this way. I am trying to find a way around it.

Comment: So you actually want to hack this website?

Comment: no. just want to use data from the website for my application if possible

Comment: @Jonathan Low - Trying to access data from a web site in a way that they clearly do not want you to access it is the very definition of 'hacking'. Don't expect to get help with that here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If the server sends a redirect header, you can of course choose not to follow it, but the page body would still be empty if the server side doesn't generate it.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to have access to data the webmaster doesn't want you to have. Just contact the webmaster and ask for it to achieve this in a proper way.